# Implement Peterson Lock in Java

Tags: java, concurrency, locking

I'm trying to implement [Peterson's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peterson%27s_algorithm) in Java, and have created the following for the moment

```
public class Peterson {
    private volatile boolean[] flag = new boolean[2];
    private volatile int victim;

    public void lock(int id)
    {
        //System.out.println(id);
        int i = id;
        int j = 1 - id; 
        flag[i] = true;
        victim = i;
        while (flag[j] && victim == i) {};
    }

    public void unlock(int id)
    {
        flag[id] = false;
    }
}
```

I got the following code to test the lock ...

```
class Counter {
    private int value;

    public Counter(int c)   {
        value = c;
    }

    public int get()
    {
        return value;
    }

    public int getAndIncrement()    {       
        return value++;
    }
}


class Thread1 implements Runnable   {
    private Counter c;
    private int id;
    private List<Integer> values;
    private Peterson lock;

    public Thread1(Counter c, int id, List<Integer> values, Peterson l) {
        this.c = c;
        this.id = id;
        this.values = values;
        this.lock = l;
    }

    public void run() {

        while (true)
        {
            lock.lock(id);
            try {
                try {

                    if (c.get() > 20000)
                        return;

                    int n = c.getAndIncrement();
                    values.add(n);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            finally {
                lock.unlock(id);
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Tmp    {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException   {

        Counter  c = new Counter(1);
        Thread[] t = new Thread[2];
        List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Peterson l =  new Peterson();

        for (int i = 0; i < t.length; ++i)  {
            t[i] = new Thread(new Thread1(c, i, values, l));
            t[i].start();
        }

        System.out.println(values.size());
    }
}
```

and although I expect `System.out.println(values.size());` to print `20000` It print on each run different numbers. Why is this? What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't create a memory barrier when you unlock to guarantee the happens before

add a `volatile boolean barr` and write true to it in unlock and change the while in the lock to `while (barr && flag[j] && victim == i) {};`

that and you don't wait on the threads you created

```
for (int i = 0; i < t.length; ++i)  {
    t[i] = new Thread(new Thread1(c, i, values, l));
    t[i].start();
}

for (int i = 0; i < t.length; ++i)  {
    try{
        t[i].join();
    }catch(InterruptedException e){
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();//don't expect it but good practice to handle anyway
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont get what you mean with `barr`, I should set `barr = true` in `unlock`, how about in `lock` method?

Comment: @mario you want actions prior to the unlock to *happen before* an actions subsequent to a successful lock, so you only need to read `barr` in lock (the *happens before* with `volatile`s are only guaranteed on the same field)

Answer (score 0):

I guess, it's because `lock()` method in Lock class isn't atomic. Specifically, this code modifies *two* memory addresses and then checks condition using both of them w/o locking:

```
public void lock(int id)
{
    ...
    flag[i] = true;
    victim = i;
    while (flag[j] && victim == i) {};
}
```

Will algorithm work if two threads interleave while executing

```
    flag[i] = true;
    victim = i;
```

Secondly, because `private volatile boolean[] flag = new boolean[2]` marks array reference as volatile, not array contents.

Comment: I didnt understand your first sentence, what you mean "lock" in Lock class isn't atomic? About the second, is there a way to mark array elements as volatile?

Comment: For `volatile` 2-booleans array, what about substituting it with volatile int with 4 possible values?

Comment: @victor that's not really acceptable because what if thread 0 sets bit 0 to true while thread 1 sets bit 1 to true using `flag = flag|1<<id;` (this is like the standard issue with increment: load->alter->store) either 01, 10 (both incorrect) or 11 (correct) you need a atomic compare and swap to solve this with an int

Answer (score 0):

As the other guys pointed out, Java has no volatile read/write on array elements.

You can use `AtomicIntegerArray` which has `get()` and `set()` with volatile effects.

Answer (score -2):

It doesn't work because you made the array reference volatile , not the content (as already pointed out). But you can always wrap a volatile field in a class and make an array of that.